# Custom attribute causes custom element styles to be re-injected into head

Tags: aurelia, shadow-dom

In my aurelia application, one of my custom elements `panel` (shadow DOM) includes another custom element `widget` (shadow DOM) that has a custom attribute `own-attribute` (template controller) on it. `panel` has a scoped stylesheet (`<require from="./panel.css" as="scoped"></require>`). While compiling, aurelia correctly injects `./panel.css` into the shadow root of `panel`. However, in a separate step, while compiling `own-context` on `widget` within `panel`, aurelia injects `./panel.css` into `<head>`, thus breaking the abstraction of custom element stylesheets and generally playing havoc with my app.

How do I fix this?

I tried making a plunker [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/L065Tu/) but it doesn't work. I'm using ES2017 so that makes life more complicated.

---

- `panel` is being compiled by [`ViewCompiler.compile()`](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/f13620127cc5d22d2943a9b3778c91ef96e248ba/src/view-compiler.js#L77)
- This [calls `ViewCompiler._compileNode()`](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/f13620127cc5d22d2943a9b3778c91ef96e248ba/src/view-compiler.js#L98)
- This [calls itself](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/f13620127cc5d22d2943a9b3778c91ef96e248ba/src/view-compiler.js#L153) on `widget`
- This [calls `ViewCompiler._compileElement()`](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/f13620127cc5d22d2943a9b3778c91ef96e248ba/src/view-compiler.js#L129) on `widget`
- This detects `own-context` as a "lifting instruction" and [calls `HtmlBehaviorResource.compile()`](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/f13620127cc5d22d2943a9b3778c91ef96e248ba/src/view-compiler.js#L417)
- This [calls `ViewCompiler.compile()`](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/f13620127cc5d22d2943a9b3778c91ef96e248ba/src/html-behavior.js#L238) on `widget`
- As a [`beforeCompile` `invokeHook`](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/f13620127cc5d22d2943a9b3778c91ef96e248ba/src/view-compiler.js#L95), [`CSSViewEngineHooks.beforeCompile()`](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources/blob/master/src/css-resource.js#L64), is called, which injects a bunch of styles into `<head>`

This is an issue. `HtmlBehaviorResource.compile()`'s call to `ViewResource.compile()` does not pass a compile instruction, so the latter uses the default. Thus the CSS hooks don't get the message that they should be injecting into the shadow root. Not to mention this is double-injecting these styles for no good reason.

```
at eval (eval at injectStyles (http://example.com/jspm/npm/aurelia-pal-browser@1.1.0/aurelia-pal-browser.js), <anonymous>:1:11)
at Object.injectStyles (http://example.com/jspm/npm/aurelia-pal-browser@1.1.0/aurelia-pal-browser.js:434:27)
at ViewCSS.beforeCompile (http://example.com/jspm/npm/aurelia-templating-resources@1.2.0/css-resource.js:105:25)
at ViewResources._invokeHook (http://example.com/jspm/npm/aurelia-templating@1.2.0/aurelia-templating.js:1281:25)
at ViewCompiler.compile (http://example.com/jspm/npm/aurelia-templating@1.2.0/aurelia-templating.js:2509:17)
at HtmlBehaviorResource.compile (http://example.com/jspm/npm/aurelia-templating@1.2.0/aurelia-templating.js:3972:46)
at ViewCompiler._compileElement (http://example.com/jspm/npm/aurelia-templating@1.2.0/aurelia-templating.js:2813:40)
at ViewCompiler._compileNode (http://example.com/jspm/npm/aurelia-templating@1.2.0/aurelia-templating.js:2543:23)
at ViewCompiler._compileNode (http://example.com/jspm/npm/aurelia-templating@1.2.0/aurelia-templating.js:2565:33)
at ViewCompiler.compile (http://example.com/jspm/npm/aurelia-templating@1.2.0/aurelia-templating.js:2512:12)
```

---

#### panel.js

```
import { useShadowDOM, customElement } from 'aurelia-templating';

export { PanelModule };

@useShadowDOM
@customElement('panel-elem')
class PanelModule {}
```

#### panel.html

```
<template>
    <require from="./panel.css" as="scoped"></require>

    <require from="lib:widget"></require>
    <require from="lib:own-context"></require>

    <widget-elem own-context>
        <content>
            some content
        </content>
    </widget-elem>
</template>
```

#### widget.js

```
import { useShadowDOM, customElement } from 'aurelia-templating';

export { WidgetModule };

@useShadowDOM
@customElement('widget-elem')
class WidgetModule {}
```

#### widget.html

```
<template>
    <require from="./widget.css" as="scoped"></require>

    <div id="thing">
        <slot></slot>
    </div
</template>
```

#### own-context.js

```
import { inject, templateController, BoundViewFactory, ViewSlot } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { createOverrideContext } from 'aurelia-binding';

// from https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/411
@templateController
@inject(BoundViewFactory, ViewSlot)
class OwnContextCustomAttribute {
    constructor(factory, slot) {
        this.factory = factory; 
        this.slot = slot;
    }

    bind(bindingContext, overrideContext) {
        let newContext = { };
        overrideContext = createOverrideContext(newContext, overrideContext); 

        if (!this.view) {
            this.view = this.factory.create(); 
            this.view.bind(newContext, overrideContext); 
            this.slot.add(this.view); 
        } else { 
            this.view.bind(newContext, overrideContext); 
        } 
    }

    unbind() {
        if (this.view)
            this.view.unbind();
    }
}
```

---

## Update

I seem to have things working. I patched `aurelia/templating-resources/css-resource.js`:

```
 beforeCompile(content: DocumentFragment, resources: ViewResources, instruction: ViewCompileInstruction): void {
+  if (this.done) {
+      return
+  } else {
+      this.done = true
+  }
   if (instruction.targetShadowDOM) {
     DOM.injectStyles(this.css, content, true);
   } else if (FEATURE.scopedCSS) {
     let styleNode = DOM.injectStyles(this.css, content, true);
     styleNode.setAttribute('scoped', 'scoped');
   } else if (!this.owner._alreadyGloballyInjected) {
     DOM.injectStyles(this.css);
     this.owner._alreadyGloballyInjected = true;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Would you mind filing an issue on our framework repo about this so some discussion of this can be had over there?

Comment: Will do. I wasn't sure if this was a bug or something I was doing wrong.

Comment: Make sure to mention at the top of your issue that I asked you to file an issue so that I don't get all grumpy and close your issue :-)

Comment: @AshleyGrant cross-posted [aurelia/framework#805](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/805)